# Which pronunciation is right of this dua?

Tags: hadith, dua, arabic, pronunciation

This dua from [bukhari 6369](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/66)

اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنَ الْهَمِّ وَالْحَزَنِ، وَالْعَجْزِ وَالْكَسَلِ، وَالْجُبْنِ وَالْبُخْلِ، وَضَلَعِ الدَّيْنِ، وَغَلَبَةِ الرِّجَالِ ‏"

The first part of this dua is pronounced as "Allahumma inni a’oo-zu bika mi-nal-ham-mi wal-**hazn**,"

But a sheikh in [**youtube**](https://youtu.be/Tmm4u7C7-pY) pronounced that part as "Allahumma inni a’oo-zu bika mi-nal-ham-mi wal-**huzn**,"

Which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them is right.
As written in the original text it is:

> وَالْحَزَنِ
> wal-Hazan(i).

not:

> وَالحٌزْنِ
> wal-Huzn(i)

nor

> وَالحَزْنِ
> wal-Hazn(i)

A full transliteration of this du'a can be found in [Hisn al-Muslim](https://sunnah.com/hisn/138).